# How to bundle typescript with webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm new to webpack.
i want to bundle my project which is written in typescript but the destination file has the same codes of typescript which are not readable by browser so what is the messing step in my configuration bellow?
The project works fine using script tags in html but i need to make them as bundle and make minified file after that.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "filemanager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "controls files using http for web hosting that has no FTP protocol.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
        "./ts/app.ts"
    ]
}
```

**wepback.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports={
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: './ts/app.ts',
    output:{
        path: './build',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    rules:[{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "ts/"),
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
    resolve:{
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    // watch: true
}
```

my app path is **./ts/app.ts**

```
import { controler } from './control'; // error stop here "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"
import { Injector }  from './Injector'; 

window.onload = ()=>{
    var DI = new Injector;
    DI.process(controler);
}
```

**Injector.ts**

```
export class Injector{

    private dependencies = {};
    process(target){
        let mainFun = null,
            // tmpFun = ()=>{},
            // FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m,
            // FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/,
            // FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/,
            // STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg,
            // text = target[2].toString(),
            // args = text.match(FN_ARGS)[1].replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');
            args = [];

        for(let key in target){
            if(typeof target[key] != 'function'){
                args.push(target[key]);
            }else{
                mainFun = target[key];
                break;
            }
        }
        // console.log(args, mainFun);

        // tmpFun.prototype = mainFun.prototype;
        // var instance = new tmpFun();
        // console.log(tmpFun.prototype);

        mainFun.prototype.constructor.apply(mainFun.prototype, this.getDependencies(args) );
        // return instance;
    }
    getDependencies(arr){        
        return arr.map( (value)=>{
            return this.dependencies[value];
        });            
    }
    register(name, dependency){
        this.dependencies[name] = new dependency;
    }

};
```

**control.ts**

```
declare var $: any;
declare var Promise: any;
export let controler = ['IMModel','IMView',class IMControl{
    private im_model        : any;
    private im_view         : any;
    private wh              : number;       // save document height;
    private ww              : number;       // save document width;
    private siteMap         = $('.aside');
    private nextContainer   : any;          // store the next container for the new directories
    public loadedPaths      = [];           // used to store all directories in aside menu to save repated requests
    public loadedFiles      = [];           // used to store all files to save repated requests
    private currentPath     = null          // used to store current path for upload new files in a specific directory
    private currentItem     = null          // used to store current item to be ready with any selection choices
    private searchResult    = [];
    private pathNavigator   = $('.navbar .path');
    private filesList       = $('.explorer .filesList');
    private isUploading     : boolean = false;
    private isAJAXFinished  : boolean = true; // This is used to hold any action till response come back.
    private newRequestReady : boolean = true; // This is used to check if the are more files to be loaded from the server otherwise it will be false.
    private items           = [];
    private itemsIterations = 0;
    private page            = 1;
    private defaultPath  : any = [{
                                        type: 'folder',
                                        name: 'Root',
                                        path: './img',
                                        ext: 'folder',
                                        chuldren: null
                                    }];
    private filesTypeMap    = { 'avi'       :'<i class="fa fa-file-video-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                'php'       :'<i class="fa fa-file-code-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                'mkv'       : '<i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                'mp4'       : '<i class="fa fa-video-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                'folder'    : '<i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                                'default'   : '<i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i>'   };
    constructor(IMModel, IMView){
        this.im_model       = IMModel;
        this.im_view        = IMView;
        this.onInit();
    }
    // rest of the code
}];
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solve my issue after a major research. for any extra information you can see my webpack template that i made.

This solve my issue here

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist/*",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -d --progress --watch",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server",
    "mini": "npm-run-all clean prod",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean dev"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

**webpack.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const publicPath = 'assets/';

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    disable: isProd,
    allChunks: true

});
const extractHtml = new htmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Admin Panal',
    minify:{
        collapseWhitespace: false
    },
    hash: true,
    template: './src/index.html' // Load a custom template (ejs by default see the FAQ for details)
});

var isProd  = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // this will return true or false depend on package.json
    cssDev  = ["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"],
    cssProd = extractSass.extract({
        use:[{
                loader: "css-loader", // translates SASS into Common CSS
                options: {sourceMap: true, convertToAbsoluteUrls: true } // convertTo.. will resolve images path
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }],
        fallback: "style-loader"
    });
var cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd: cssDev;
module.exports={
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        compress: true,
        stats: "errors-only",
        watchContentBase: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        open: true,
        port: 9000,
        openPage: ''
    },
    devtool: "source-map", // show .map files for better debugging.
    entry: './src/ts/app.ts',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.scss', '.css']
    },
    module:{
        rules: 
        [{   
            test: /\.scss$/, 
            use: cssConfig
        },{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|json|xml|ico)(\?.*)?$/i,
            loader: [
                'file-loader?name='+publicPath+'[name].[ext]',
                {
                    loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                    options: 
                    {
                        query: 
                        {
                            progressive: true,
                            optimizationLevel: 7,
                            interlaced: false,
                            pngquant:
                            {
                                quality: '65-90',
                                speed: 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [ extractHtml, extractSass,
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()]
}
```

This is a reference to the template.

[Webpack_Template](https://github.com/AhmedBHameed/Webpack_Template)

Comment: For other readers for future reference it is useful (and more reliable than a link) to summarize the main points that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks @KoertvanKleef for the  note. I update the replay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with `ts-loader` so I don't know if it is of any good,  I use `awesome-typescript-loader` to transpile my typescript code with webpack. So first step is to install it via `npm i -D awesome-typescript-loader`, then modify your webpack config file like so

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports={
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: './ts/app.ts',
    output:{
        path: './build',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    rules:[{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "ts/"),
        use: "awesome-typescript-loader", // Change here
        exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
    resolve:{
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    // watch: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dummy but still the same issue.
I thing that javascript does not understand import in ES5 so it shoud be converted to the equivalent code BUT the code still the same inside my .js file. Can you provide me with the tsconfig.ts configuration may be there are some thing different!!

Comment: Add `"target": "es5"` to your tsconfig file